# difference between 2 different ways to set logging level with python logging module

Tags: python, python-logging

What is the difference between the following 2 ways to set the log levels and is there a certain use case for either?

`logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`

`logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`

I ask this question because I used one rather than the other and it lead to this weird repeat logging output:

```
(envCSSS) csss@csss-website:~/csss-site-in-dev/csss-site/src$ python3.7 manage.py getmail
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] BASE_DIR set to /home/csss
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] DEBUG set to True
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] ROOT_DIR set to /home/csss/csss-site-in-dev
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] STATIC_URL set to /STATIC_URL/
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] STATIC_ROOT set to /home/csss/static_root/
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] MEDIA_URL set to /MEDIA_URL/
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] MEDIA_ROOT set to /home/csss/media_root/
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] FILE_FORM_MASTER_DIR set to form_uploads/form_uploads/
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] FILE_FORM_UPLOAD_DIR set to form_uploads/form_uploads/temporary_files/
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] DJANGO_MAILBOX_ATTACHMENT_UPLOAD_TO set to mailbox_attachments/%Y/%m/%d/
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
.....................
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
```

`setLevel` cause the above issue and I had to swap it out for `basicConfig` to correct the logging issue.

Comment: You should show the code where you are configuring the logger and where you are using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation itself is self explanatory:

[`logger.setLevel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel)

Here, `logger` seems is an instance of a `Logger`. By using `setLevel` you are setting the threshold level for this particular logger.

[`logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)

> Does basic configuration for the logging system by creating a `StreamHandler` with a default `Formatter` and adding it to the root logger. The functions `debug()`, `info()`, `warning()`, `error()` and `critical()` will call `basicConfig()` automatically if no handlers are defined for the root logger.

Calling `basicConfig` will setup a logger with handler and formatter if a root logger is not already defined. If you pass `level` here it will be set to the level of the root logger.

As you will notice that `setLevel` is available on a `logger` instance while `basicConfig` is available on the `logging` module.